# Can a user multi-post?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, cross-posting

Is a user allowed to post the same question on multiple Stack exchange sites?

For example, what if a user posted the same question on both Superuser and Stackoverflow?

Or, should the user just wait for answers on one site?

Comment: That's called "cross-posting".

Comment: @AlEverett It is, and that's the term I use, but "multi-post" is also an acceptable term and [arguably a better one, since cross-posting has another meaning too](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1482/22949).

Comment: That's as may be, but around _here_ "cross post" is the common term, and if one wants to find out information _already_ established here, one will find more information under "cross-post" than "multi-post".

Answer (score 3):

Cross posting is frowned on.

It makes migrations really difficult.

If you have a question that can fit on a couple of sites, decide which on it is more suitable on and ask there. If, and **only if** you are not getting any answers within a few days, consider asking again on the other relevant site, linking to the original and explaining you didn't get any answers there.

Comment: I'd also add that you should tailor the question to the site's audience as well. It's rarely true that *exactly* the same question is on topic on multiple sites, but questions on the same topic but asked from different perspectives with different emphasis might be,

Answer (score 2):

If you post it on one site, it is probably off topic on the other site. Do not post your question on multiple sites; read the FAQ page of the sites and decide which site would be best to ask on.

If you're **really** not sure, you can ask on meta with the tag [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec).

Comment: And how does one report this sort of case? I'll post this as a separate question.

Comment: @JasjeevSingh Flag one of the posts.

Comment: Ok :) no need for another question